# Pandas - KeyError while merging DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I need to merge the below two dataframes:

```
df1

    PointA    LineA   PointB      ID

0     A        2        D   
1     A        3        K
2     B        2        F   
3     C        3        M   


df2

   PointA   LineA    ID 
0    A         2       129
1    A         2       233
2    A         2       560
3    A         3       321
4    A         3       340
5    B         2       213
```

Desired Output:

```
   PointA    LineA   PointB   ID
0   A          2        D      129
1   A          2        D      233
2   A          2        D      560
3   A          3        K      321
4   A          3        K      340
5   B          2        F      213
6   C          3        M
```

I've used the below code:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1[['PointA','LineA','PointB']],
                 on=[['PointA','LineA']], 
                 how='Left')
```

I've the following error:

```
KeyError: ['PointA', 'LineA']
```

Can Somebody please help me out with what's wrong.?
I've gone through some of the other similar questions and checked the indexing and similar issues but none seem to work.

Comment: What is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael it's `['PointA', 'LineA', 'PointB', 'ID']`

Comment: OK, what about `print (df2.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael it's `['PointA', 'LineA', 'ID']` I have checked the column names for whitespaces, they seem to be the same column names.

Comment: Because keyerror means there is no column `PointA`, no column `LineA`

Comment: @jezrael I'm sure that the column names are correct. I've rechecked again. df1 has been created from a xlsx file and df2 from a csv file. Does that account for such an error.?

Comment: I think I got it. Need `pd.merge(df2, df1[['PointA','LineA','PointB']],
                 on=['PointA','LineA'], 
                 how='Left') `, removed one `[]` form on parameter, can you check it?

Comment: Upon removal of the extra [] -> `Keyerror: ('PointA', 'LineA', 'PointB')`

Comment: I think remove  `[]` only from `on` parameter, not from `df1`, please check again

Comment: @jezrael That did the trick. Thanks :)